# How to save users email and name after authentication in database (Firebase)?

Tags: android, firebase

I am new to Android and new to Firebase as well. I am developing an Android app where a user creates his account with email and password.

How can I save users identity like name, address etc. along with email into Firebase Database?

Here is my code where the user is created with email and password and code for extra info about the user to save in the database.

My app is crashing after it creates a new user, and also it is not storing info in the database.

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailId, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    String user_id = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                    DatabaseReference current_user_db = reference.child(user_id);

                    current_user_db.child("FNAME").setValue(nameF);

                    current_user_db.child("LNAME").setValue(nameL);

                    current_user_db.child("EMAIL").setValue(email);

                    progress.hide();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);

                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                    startActivity(intent);

                }

        }
    });
```

Here is the Log.

```
06-17 21:01:17.082 2262-2262/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
06-17 21:01:22.096 2262-2262/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: Micro detection mode: [mDetectionMode: [1]].
06-17 21:01:22.097 2262-2262/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/AudioController: Using mInputStreamFactoryBuilder
06-17 21:01:22.103 2262-4023/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Starting detection.
06-17 21:01:22.112 2262-3576/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@4a20126
06-17 21:01:22.112 1304-1304/? W/APM_AudioPolicyManager: getInputForAttr() failed opening input: samplingRate 16000, format 1, channelMask 10
06-17 21:01:22.112 2262-3576/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for session 857, record source 1999, sample rate 16000, format 0x1, channel mask 0x10, flags 0
06-17 21:01:22.114 2262-3576/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -22.
06-17 21:01:22.114 2262-3576/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
06-17 21:01:22.114 2262-3576/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@4a20126
06-17 21:01:22.115 2262-3576/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
06-17 21:01:22.116 2262-2262/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
06-17 21:01:22.130 2262-3576/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@4a20126
06-17 21:01:22.130 2262-4023/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection finished
06-17 21:01:22.130 2262-4023/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 524300]: Error reading from input stream
06-17 21:01:22.131 2262-2432/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping hotword detection.
06-17 21:01:22.131 2262-4023/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream
  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
  at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85) 
06-17 21:01:22.131 2262-4023/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/AudioController: internalShutdown
06-17 21:01:22.133 2262-2262/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
06-17 21:01:22.133 2262-2262/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
06-17 21:01:22.133 2262-4022/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
```

Comment: Yeah so What is the problem you are going good. Store the remaining details just you did for email, name etc.

Comment: @DushyantSuthar                                                                                        this time i have changes the code little bit now my app is crashing

Comment: Can you post log?

Comment: @Asama thanks for your reply, I have posted the Log just below code

Comment: @KaushalTopinkatti in the log you posted, there's no reference about Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a HashMap (personal opinion I find it more readable) this is my code for Updating User Settings and the whole function is getting called through a button, hope this helps.

```
private void updatesettings() {
    String UserName = username.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();
    String PhoneNumber= pno.getText().toString();

    FirebaseUser user = mauth.getCurrentUser();
    String uid = user.getUid();

    //this is to enter all the details under the UID of currently logged in user

    dbr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid);

    HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    userMap.put("name", UserName);
    userMap.put("phone number", PhoneNumber);
    userMap.put("status", "jdjdjjdjdjdj");
    userMap.put("image", "default");
    userMap.put("thumbnail", "default");

    dbr.setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                // Toast.makeText(UpdateUserSettings.this, "Your settings have been updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(UpdateUserSettings.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(UpdateUserSettings.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```